# Why don't 4++ dns names resolve to the 3-- part name?

Tags: dns

Given that:

```
domain.com resolves to some IP and
www.domain.com would resolve (usually) to the same IP
```

Why don't abc.www.domain.com or a.b.c.d.domain.com resolve to the next lower available N part name by default?

Comment: Are you asking this because you expected `abc.www.domain.com ⇒ www.domain.com` to work the same way as `www.domain.com ⇒ domain.com` does?

Comment: I wanted to understand where the failure was happening with 4 part names.  In the case where a 3 part name resolved to an particular IP, it seemed mysterious that adding an additional prefix would not resolve to the same IP.

Comment: But why do you think it's different from 2-part vs 3-part names?

Comment: Even if a one part name 'machine' happened to resolve to a single IP (say via a local hosts entry), I would have expected a.b.c.machine to resolve to the same IP.  Nothing may be awry, just wanted to understand the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a difference between a host name in a zone and a delegated zone or sub-zone.

Given www.example.com the `www` is a hostname in the example.com zone.  Yes, there is a computer at example.com serving that zone but the DNS system is explicitly configured to say "www is a host here" and not "there is a subzone named www".

Of course, some DNS server software supports the use of wildcards so they could be configured to have a zone at `www.example.com` and then use a wildcard at `*.www.example.com` and have it all point to the same IP.

And of course, nothign stops anyone from creating their own DNS server software that responds in any way they want, as long as it "speaks" the DNS protocol.

Comment: True/false/comment?  "The DNS Framework does not impose a network hierarchical constraint that longer (N) part names be IP addressed as subnets of (N-1) names so each N part name must resolve completely against an explicit DNS entry (including wildcards) else the lookup fails."

Answer (score 0):

The actual relationship here is the exact opposite of what you think.  Domain.com is not a fallback address for www.domain.com.  Domain.com is the name of all possible addresses ending in domain.com **and** has been linked explicitly to www.domain.com in the DNS records.  The World Wide Web is not the only, or even the oldest, service to use the Internet and if the organization that owns domain.com didn't have a website they could just as easily have linked it to mail.domain.com or ftp.domain.com.  In cases of organizations that aren't explicitly only websites the domain is often the suffix for all machines within their network and the link could be assigned to any of them or a pool of machines.

Going up a level of DNS usually means crossing an organizational boundary.  In this case domain.com is owned by the hypothetical example company and it makes sense to send people attempting to reach it to their website. On the other hand the com. domain is owned by Verisign, a major player in DNS who would have no way to know which of it's many, many customers you were actually interested in.

Comment: *domain.com is the name of a network as well as a host*... I'm not sure what you're saying here. What do you mean by "network" in this context?

Comment: Think the internet resources and possibly intranet of a single company.  In theory, and in practice for large organizations, each domain has it's own DNS servers which are the authority for addresses only on that domain.  Each address on the domain may be a host, or it may be a subdomain,  And that subdomain may have it's own DNS servers.  The convention is that domain.com have an alias to www.domain.com as well as identify the entire domain, not that domain.com be a fallback for www.domain.com

Comment: The term *network* isn't a term usually employed when discussing fully qualified DNS hostnames, so I'm unsure what your answer is trying to say about "domain.com is a network."

Answer (score 0):

> Even if a one part name 'machine' happened to resolve to a single IP (say via a local hosts entry), I would have expected a.b.c.machine to resolve to the same IP.

/etc/hosts entries are not DNS; I think they actually *predate* DNS and the concept of multi-level dotted names. Before inventing DNS, most systems just used single-word names and `a.b.c.machine` wasn't really a thing.

As for DNS itself, it's simply a choice that its inventors made that only explicitly created names would be resolvable by default, with no 'magic' features like automatic expansion.

So when you see `www.example.com` resolve to some address, that's because the domain's owner *actually added* the individual subdomain "www" to their DNS zone – not because DNS automatically duplicates it.

---

Note that DNS actually *does* have this as an *opt-in* feature. If you create a DNS entry for `*.example.com` (at any level), then all unknown subdomains at the same level (e.g. `foo.example.com`) will automatically be resolved to the same data as the `*` entry. This is actually used for many website hosting systems; e.g. GitHub has a `*.github.io` entry to automatically catch all usernames.

But in practice, it does make things *annoying* in many cases (outside of the web). If a domain has opted in to using wildcards, every time you make a typo in the subdomain, you no longer get an actual error message saying that you messed up the name – instead it quietly goes to somewhere completely different than you wanted.